# What UI elements do you use to display information in real time?

Tags: gui-design, material-design

If some string like "Now executing cronjob...", "REST call made", "Authorization successful", "Cronjob complete", etc. need to be shown every 1-2 second, what UI elements would you use? I looked at the Material-UI libraries and there's no component for showing transient elements rapidly like that. Most information are shown for 5-6 seconds with the notification UI elements used on most Material-UI components. Also, do you have sources that supports your suggestions?

Comment: What's the larger context this constant transient element lives in? What is the user engaged in while this message keeps showing up? This forum works best when you provide some visuals showing the larger context (and your efforts so far), so the community can help with more specific answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [SnackBar](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-snackbar/) which is a flow-on-top UI indicating some running background tasks and it doesn't block the user's interaction with the rest of the UI.

On desktop, you can position them on the bottom right if it doesn't clash with any existing elements like the Intercom bubble etc, and you might want to color them green for Success/Complete states.

Comment: It won't display information in real-time. Since it's not made for that.